# How to do Data Annotations on an object in another Assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, data-annotations

I have an **abstract domain object** that is consumed by both a **web** and **windows** application. This domain object sits in a an old namespace along with any derived classes.

For my web application I would like to use **data annotations**. Usually I would create a **partial class** to the **domain object** and provide it a **MetaData** class. However, I am unable to touch the namespace where the **domain objects** reside and there lies my problem.

Is there any solution for providing partial classes/metadata to domain objects in another namespace? Remember I can't touch the domain objects namespace at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataAnnotations works by decorating properties on a type with attributes, or by decorating the actual type with a `MetadataTypeAttribute` that points at the actual class that holds the validation attributes.

If you can't touch it, you can't use DataAnnotations. It's as simple as that. You might try try some code weaving technique such as [CCI](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) to change the assembly without touching the code, but in the end you are still touching it.

You need to pick a different validation framework. One that allows to separate the validation configuration completely from the actual code: You clearly need [Enterprise Library Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664356%28PandP.50%29.aspx), because it allows you to put the validations in a (XML) configuration file.

Good luck.

Comment: Thought as much. Thanks. I even tried creating a partial class in a different assembly but with same namespace as the domain object and then applying the MetdataTypeAttribute on the partial class but then there were compile errors about ambiguity. I'll take a look at Enterprise Library Validation Application Block.

Comment: Just saw how old this question was.  hmm, really hitting the graveyard today I am.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this, its not impossible and its not a huge chore either.

Simply create a new class that inherits from your domain class and lives inside your web project. This will be your view model. Attribute the view model class you just created with a `MetadataTypeAttribute` that references the class containing the data attributes describing your validation, display etc..

That's it, simple as pie.

Comment: This actually doesn't work.

Comment: this was from 2016, the technology has moved on likely since this answer was posted.  At the time of the writing, this worked just fine and I had used it.